# Faking the find method in FakeDbSet implementation

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, moq

I want to unit test a controller that takes a `FormCollection` and has the `Find` method. I have successfully implemented a fake `DbContext` and a `FakeDbSet` (from [here](http://coding.grax.com/2013/04/FakeDbSet.html)) so that I can use the fake objects in my tests.

The specific method I want to test looks like this:

```
    //
    // POST: /Order/SettleOrders

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult SettleOrders(FormCollection c)
    {
        int i = 0;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var ordersCollection = new List<Order>();

            // Get values of form
            var OrderIdArray = c.GetValues("item.OrderId");
            var UnitPriceArray = c.GetValues("item.UnitPrice");

            for (i = 0; i < OrderIdArray.Count(); i++)
            {
                // Find order in database and update the unitprice and isconfirmed status
                Order order = db.Orders.Find(Convert.ToInt32(OrderIdArray[i]));
                order.UnitPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(UnitPriceArray[i]);
                order.IsConfirmed = true;
                db.SetModified(order);
                ordersCollection.Add(order);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        // Return orders of this date to view
        var currentDate = DateTime.Today;
        var orders = db.Orders.Include(o => o.Product)
                                .Include(o => o.User)
                                .Where(o => o.Date == currentDate);
        return View("Confirmation", orders.ToList().OrderBy(o => o.User.Name));
    }
```

This is how I set up the test of my `OrderController` using `Moq`:

```
[TestInitialize]
    public void OrderControllerTestInitialize()
    {
        // Arrange 
        var unconfirmedMemoryItems = new FakeOrderSet
        {
            // @TODO Tests/methods should ideally not be dependent on DateTime.Today...
            new Order { OrderId = 1, UnitPrice = 1.00M, Quantity = 2, Date = DateTime.Today, IsConfirmed = false },
            new Order { OrderId = 2, UnitPrice = 2.00M, Quantity = 1, Date = DateTime.Today, IsConfirmed = false }
        };

        // Create mock unit of work
        var unconfirmedMockData = new Mock<ISeashellBrawlContext>();
        unconfirmedMockData.Setup(m => m.Orders).Returns(confirmedMemoryItems);

        // Setup controller
        unconfirmedOrderController = new OrderController(confirmedMockData.Object);
    }
```

Then the test goes likes this to confirm the unconfirmed orders are becoming confirmed.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestSettleOrdersPost()
    {
        // Invoke
        FormCollection form = CreatesettleOrdersPostFormCollection();
        var viewResult = unconfirmedOrderController.SettleOrders(form) as ViewResult;
        var ordersFromView = (IEnumerable<Order>)viewResult.Model;

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(3, ordersFromView.ElementAt(0).Quantity,
            "New item should be added to older one since it has same index and is of same date");
        Assert.AreEqual(true, ordersFromView.ElementAt(0).IsConfirmed,
           "The item should also be set to confirmed");
    }

    // Helper methods

    private static FormCollection CreatesettleOrdersPostFormCollection()
    {
        FormCollection form = new FormCollection();
        form.Add("item.OrderId", "1");
        form.Add("item.UnitPrice", "2.00");
        form.Add("item.OrderId", "2");
        form.Add("item.UnitPrice", "3.00");
        return form;
    }
```

Unfortunately I get the following error message:

> Test Name:    TestSettleOrdersPost
>   Result Message:
>
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object. Result StackTrace:   at
>   Controllers.OrderController.SettleOrders(FormCollection c) in
>   Controllers\OrderController.cs:line 121

This probably has to do with the fake `Find` method not doing what it is supposed to do. The find method I use looks like this:

```
class FakeOrderSet : FakeDbSet<Order>
{
    public override Order Find(params object[] keyValues)
    {
        var id = Convert.ToInt32(keyValues[0]);
        Order o = null;

        IQueryable<Order> keyQuery = this.AsQueryable<Order>();
        foreach (var order in keyQuery)
        {
            if (order.OrderId == id)
            {
                o = order;
            }
        }

        return o;
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to improve this code. Looking at it I am convinced it should work. Since I am a 7-day noob to unit testing this conviction is of not much worth though. I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: _"This probably has to do"_ ... put a breakpoint before line 121 and see what happens.

Comment: @CodeCaster How do I put a breakpoint in code when I am doing unittests? I cannot manage to do that and I can also not write to console... Having these tools available would be a huge help. Ah I found an answer:  `Debug` -> `Tests In Current Context` (or otherwise)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594018/cannot-debug-a-unit-testing-project-in-visual-studio-2012 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103712/stepping-through-and-debugging-code-in-unit-tests. Right-click the test in Test Explorer and click Debug if other ways don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can include `Find` method implementation in your generic `FakeDbSet<T>` class.
For example if all your entites have property `Id` that is mapped to primary key in database you can do following:

```
public class FakeDbSet<T>
{
  ....

  public T Find(params object[] keyvalues)
  {
    var keyProperty = typeof(T).GetProperty(
            "Id", 
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public |  BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
    var result = this.SingleOrDefault(obj => 
        keyProperty.GetValue(obj).ToString() == keyValues.First().ToString());
    return result;
  }
}
```

If your key property is not `Id` you can try to determine some algorith how to recognize key property for the entity via reflection (for example if `Order` class have `OrderId` key property you can try to determine it by getting class name with reflection and concatenating it with "Id" string).

Comment: Yes this was an option, and then also make all your fake objects get assigned an id. I did not get this to work though. Fortunately I found what the mistake was (I did not post a bit of code related to that since I thought it was not relevant), my method did work since I should have also initialized a User `FakeDbSet` since it was writing something to that! The `Find` method was working after all.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem:

```
    public override TEntity Find(params object[] keyValues)
    {
        if (keyValues.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("keyValues");
        return this.SingleOrDefault(GenerateKeyFilter(keyValues));
    }

    private Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> GenerateKeyFilter(object[] keyValues)
    {
        var conditions = new List<BinaryExpression>();
        var objectParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity));

        var keyFields = !!!Helper.KeyFields<TEntity>();

        if (keyFields.Count != keyValues.Length)
            throw new KeyNotFoundException();
        for (var c = 0; c < keyFields.Count; c++)
            conditions.Add(Expression.MakeBinary(
                ExpressionType.Equal,
                Expression.MakeMemberAccess(objectParam, keyFields[c]),
                Expression.Constant(keyValues[c], keyFields[c].PropertyType)
                ));
        var result = conditions[0];
        for (var n = 1; n < conditions.Count; n++)
            result = Expression.And(result, conditions[n]);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(result, objectParam);
    }
```

This works well, however, to create the tests I had to reconfigure the models and manually set the keys, similar to use of **EntityTypeConfiguration**.